# How to see list of votes I made?

Tags: support, voting

I want to know how many votes I made on questions and answer's still. Is there any way to know that ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your profile page, you can find a summary of your votes at the bottom.

But to see the detailed history of your votes, click on the `votes` tab in the your profile.

In your case, the page for your profile is at http://meta.askubuntu.com/users/263205/a-j?tab=votes. (Votes are private, so this page is private for your eyes only. Not even mods can see it.)

[image: Profile page header]